# Shield effect on Mantra of Healing?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

After today's patch I've noticed that whenever I cast Mantra of Healing I got a shimmering bubble around me and my followers, at first I took it simply as an added effect to show that I have the Sustenance rune equipped, but at one point I was hit by a fireball just after using the Mantra and the damage was absorbed which I have not experienced before, leading me to the conclusion that my Mantra somehow did it. However, the description does not state any damage absorption nor do I even have access to the rune that actually adds a shield.

So is this a bug? or a new effect that the tooltip hasn't been updated with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an intended change:

> **Mantra of Healing** (tooltips will be updated in a later patch)
>  In
>   addition to increasing Life regeneration for you and nearby allies
>   while active, Mantra of Healing will now also shroud you and nearby
>   allies with a mystical shield that absorbs damage for 3 seconds after
>   activiation (up to a limited amount, based on level)

[Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6020042)

Comment: and that limited amount is 1000 hp, which is pretty crappy

Comment: @xy Is this fix? Doesn't scale?